# Margin-left with ng-repeat working for first element only

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, haml, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having a very unusual issue, and I'm not entirely sure where the problem lies.

I've got an `ng-repeat` call that looks like this

```
    .data.row.vote-entry{ "ng-repeat" => "option in agendaItem.conclusions"}
        .cast-vote
          %a{:href => "#", "ng-click" => "voteForConclusion(option)", "ng-class" => "{active: option.id == votedConclusion.id}"}
            =image_tag "icons/icon-conclude.png"

        .title
          %span {{option.description}}
```

It's pretty simple and works perfectly.

Now, for each of the `.data.row.vote-entry` elements, I have the css rule

```
margin-left: 4%;
```

applied so the row is offset from the left side. It works perfectly for the first item of the `ng-repeat`, however the problems arise when there is more than one item in the loop. When the page loads, the first item is in the correct place, however all of the others are to the far left as if they've completely ignored the CSS rule.

Sometimes, they will bounce into place very soon after loading, but other times they just stay where they are. If I inspect the page with something like firebug, the CSS rules are all in place, and weirdly, if I disable the margin rule, and then re-enable it, they then ALL go to the correct place, so I'm really confused as to why this is happening.

Can someone give me a clue as to what might be going on here as I'm really stumped!

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrV7J/) demonstrating part of the problem. Unfortunately it isn't demonstrating how the bars stay too far to the left (couldn't quite reproduce that one) but it does show how the bars start too far to the left and then jump to the right place after

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you change the margin from 4% to 20px, does it work for all elements then?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of the problem?

Comment: @RobR yeah it seems to work fine if I set it to a fixed size. I'm just reluctant to use a fixed size as the page is meant to be fluid but if it's the only option then I may do.

Comment: @user2019515 I've added a fiddle now :)

Comment: I don't see anything unusual with the jsfiddle, what is the problem?

Comment: Well the fiddle doesn't show the full problem sadly. In the fiddle, certainly on my laptop in Chrome, the bottom 6 bars when rendered start on the left of the screen, however they should have a 4% left margin. It then jumps into the correct place, but I don't like the fact it is doing this. I've just run it again however and they haven't jumped back so it is showing the problem sometimes. It's not every single time, but intermittently.

Comment: Right, that's why I said try pixels first. I think your objects are injected into the DOM before the 4% can be calculated, so it equals 0.

Comment: hm weirdly though, if I change margin-left: 4% to left: 4% it seems to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using `left: 4%` works even if `margin-left: 4%` doesn't work properly